# .unshift is not a function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, push

I just started learning React JS, and am trying a simple project where I hit a button and a random number should be added to an array. Here is my code:

```js
function App() {
  
  const [cache2, setCache2] = useState([])

  const nextNumber = () => {
    const randomNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    const newCache = cache2.push(randomNr)
    setCache2(newCache)    
    console.log(cache2)
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>

      <button onClick = {nextNumber}>Next Number</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, it throws an "**cache2.push is not a function**" error. I cannot find out what is the problem. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `const newCache = cache2.push(randomNr)` Push returns an added element, not a new array

Comment: Never do push on state , because push mutates the original array and in react state should not be mutated directly . You need to do this instead `setCache2(currentCache => ([...currentCache, randomNr])) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a mutation function and returns the element you pushed, not the original array. Thus `setCache2(newCache)` makes `cache2` a number other than an array. So calling `push()` from a number throws you this error.

It's better to make a new array and set the state using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const nextNumber = () => {
  const randomNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  setCache2([...cache2, randomNr])
  console.log(cache2)
}
```